# Infamous "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl64 in java.library.path"

Tags: java, lwjgl

I see several posts here concerning this topic - but no fixes that I've been able to implement (IU'm using Android Studio on Windows to build a Java application).

Following the directions from the LWJGL wiki (http://wiki.lwjgl.org/wiki/Setting_Up_LWJGL_with_IntelliJ_IDEA.html) - I've created a 'libs' folder in my project, and have copied there:

```
lwjgl64.dll
```

In my launch configuration, I have tried this in my VM options:

```
 -Djava.library.path="C:\Program Files\Java\lwjgl-2.9.3\native\windows\lwjgl64.dll"
```

I have also tried adding the library path to my Environment Variables within Windows.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\lwjgl-2.9.3\native\windows\lwjgl64.dll
```

Probably an easy fix here, but I'm at my witt's end trying to figure out what it is. Pointers?

Comment: LWJGL isn't designed for android only desktop

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity... AndroidStudio is my IDE - but I am compiling a Java Application (on Windows64 PC).

Comment: `java.library.path` should point to the *directory containing the library files*. Your currently points at *a specific library file*. Follow the instructions **exactly** as printed, and you should be fine.

Comment: That's why I'm frustrated Joachim - following the directions does_not_work. Per the instructions: Create a 'libs' folder in your project, and copy the .dll's there. Done. Set VM options to: -Djava.library.path=libs/. Done. Attempt to run program: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl64 in java.library.path

Comment: @n8skow: that's not what you're describing in your post though. You set `java.library.path` to a very different value. If you give a relative path, then your working directory must be the one under `libs/` (which I think is the default, but if you changed it, that could be the problem).

Comment: Joachim - Those were 2 different solutions I've found via Google, neither of which I've been able to make work.

I do agree it seems to be a pathing issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure android studio runs your app either through emulator or in your phone via USB debugging . It isn't meant to build desktop apps even though you are running the IDE on windows.

Switch to [Intelij](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#section=windows) , [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) Or [Netbeans](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb121/index.html) as these are much more lightweight and faster compared to android studio

Once you have there are two ways you can solve your unsatisfied link error

***1) Through Code***

just above your main method in an static block set the lwjgl specific property pointing to your lib *FOLDER*

```
static
{   
 File PATH=new File("C:\\Program Files\\Java\\lwjgl\\2.9.3\\native\\windows"); //I assume you have it here

 System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath",PATH.getAbsolutePath()); //This is the property not the regular Djava.library.path
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
 //Your app
}
```

***2) Manualy***

Just copy all the dll files to your project folder Or if you have built an jar file from your project then make sure to paste the dll files in the directory containing your jar file or package all the dll files into your jar using [JarSplice](https://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Other-Programming-Files/JarSplice.shtml) check out the  video tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YqGUk84BmlQ&t=316s)

Comment: Note that Android Studio is "just" IntelliJ IDEA with a set of preconfigured plugins. AFAIK you can use it as a fully functional equivalent of IDEA CE (assuming you install all the required plugins).

Comment: True but it takes a lot of memory and comes built in with a lot of unused plugins compared to eclipse & netbeans or intelliJ just by itself which is industry standard

Comment: I selected Android Studio so I can play with Java - and migrate toward Android development. It is a bit of a resource hog, but I've not really had any performance issues with it.